# React: Redirect not firing

Tags: reactjs

In the code below, I have a get and post request that are being sent over to my backend API. In the second follow up post request I am sending the value of the applicant_id that I got back from the first get request.

When I do that, I expect to get back a data structure that looks like this `{result: "clear"}`, which I do. I store the result of that in a variable called `obj`. I then put in an `if` statement saying if `obj === "clear"` then go ahead and run this function called `renderResult()` which fires off a redirect over to my `Result` component which I have in my `App.js` file.

```
const useOnfidoFetch = (URL) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  const [id, setId] = useState();
  const [isClear, setIsClear] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/post_stuff")
      .then((response) => response.data.data.data.json_data)
      .then((json_data) => {
        console.log("this is the json data", json_data);
        const id = json_data.applicant_id;
        const token = json_data.onfido_sdk_token;
        setId(id);
        setToken(token);
      });
  }, [URL]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) return;
    console.log("this is working!");
    OnfidoSDK.init({
      token,
      containerId: "root",
      steps: [
        {
          type: "welcome",
          options: {
            title: "Open your new bank account",
          },
        },
        "document",
      ],
      onComplete: function (data) {
        console.log("everything is complete");
        console.log("this is the applicant id", id);
        let obj;
        axios
          .post("http://localhost:5000/post_id", {
            applicant_id: id,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            obj = response.data.data.data.json_data.result;
            setIsClear(true);
          });
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (obj === "clear") {
            renderResult();
          }
        }, 3000);
      },
    });
  }, [id, token, setIsClear]);

  function renderResult() {
    return <Redirect to="/result" />;
  }
};

export default function() {
  const URL = `${transmitAPI}/anonymous_invoke?aid=onfido_webapp`;
  const result = useOnfidoFetch(URL, {});

     return (
        <div id={onfidoContainerId} />
     )
}
```

I think my achilles heel is that `<div id={onfidoContainerId} />`. I tried throwing the whole thing in the if conditional, but that did not work.

Comment: Regarding your flag, I think it's safe to leave the question open until the right person comes along. If you know what the specific solution is, you may post an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Redirect to="/result" />;` is not in the component tree. You can't just return JSX object from wherever you want and expect React to magically inject it into the component tree. It should be within the component tree. In your code, it ( `<Redirect />` ) is in a ordinary function defined inside the hook.

Try this,

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const useOnfidoFetch() {
  const history = useHistory();

  ....

  function renderResult() {
    history.push("/result");
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe your answer is sound and I will check it off, but the problem is the Onfido SDK needs to be torn down using one of its methods called `tearDown()`, but I am unable to correctly implement it. For example, I tried solution and it still does not redirect, but I do not think its because your solution is wrong, but because I need to apply that `tearDown()` method to the `OnfidoSDK`.

Comment: Yah there can be other issues which prevent the `renderResult()` from being invoking. One other issue that I can see is the `setTimeout`. You should put that code within the `then` block. How can you sure that the response from 2nd request is received within 3 seconds ? But at the end even if the `renderResult()` is invoking, the reason why it is not redirecting is `<Redirect />` is a JSX object and it is not inside the component tree.

Comment: And also make sure the React component on the bottom, is a child of `<BrowserRouter>`

Comment: yes inside my `App.js` file I have it inside of `<BrowserRouter>` and `<Switch>`.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the code and I see some issues, you have to remove the second `let obj` inside `then`, and in the condition you are comparing strings so `obj === clear` should be `obj === "clear"` your code should look like this

```
enter code here
  useEffect(() => {
if (!token) return;
console.log("this is working!");
OnfidoSDK.init({
  token,
  containerId: "root",
  steps: [
    {
      type: "welcome",
      options: {
        title: "Open your new bank account",
      },
    },
    "document",
  ],
  onComplete: function (data) {
    console.log("everything is complete");
    console.log("this is the applicant id", id);
    let obj;
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/post_id", {
        applicant_id: id,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        obj = response.data.data.data.json_data.result;
        setIsClear(true);
      });
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (obj === "clear") {
        renderResult();
      }
    }, 3000);
  },
});
}, [id, token, setIsClear]);
```

Comment: @Dharman, I posted an old version, the new one does have those changes you suggested and it still does not redirect me. I will correct this now.

Comment: I posted an old version, the new one does have those changes you suggested and it still does not redirect me.